# Does clojure-xml/parse return a lazy sequence?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

clojure-xml/parse returns a map of an xml file.

```
(ns xml-lib.core
  ^{:author "Charles M. Norton",
    :doc "xml-lib is an xml parsing library built on clojure-xml.
        Created on June 26, 2012"} 
  (:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
  (:require [util.core :as utl])
  (:require [clojure.xml :as cjxml]))

(defn ret-xml-data
    "Returns a map of the supplied xml file."
    [xml-fnam]

    (let [test-file-nam (utl/open xml-fnam)]
    (cjxml/parse xml-fnam))
```

Is the returned map lazy, or should I pass the parse call into a lazy sequence function?

Thanks.

```
(ret-xml-data "test.xml")
```

returns (result truncated).

```
{:tag :TamperExport, :attrs {:xmlns "http://
```

Comment: If you want to parse XML with Clojure lazily, I'd recommend [clojure.data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml), which is the successor to what used to be in clojure-xml from clojure-contrib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a SAX Parser under the hood, which will consume the entire xml document, so I assume that it will create the fully realized data structure.

Comment: Which means I should make it lazy? I'm assuming that because you used the phrase "fully realized". Thanks.

Comment: I mean that it is a complete data structure, so it's already there - in memory; all of it.

Comment: SAX parser doesn't necessarily mean it creates a fully realized data structure, though in this case that's correct. The old contrib.lazy-xml started the parser in a new thread which put elements into a queue, and returned a seq that pulled elements off the queue.

Answer (score 3):

the short anser is no, clojure-xml likely won't do what you want.

data.xml is the lazy sucessor to clojure-xml

https://github.com/clojure/data.xml

Comment: Thanks. I'll go look at that tomorrow.

Comment: This is useful, but it is a comment, not an answer to the question (which is "no", by the way). It could be rephrased to be an answer (nudge, nudge).