# How to elegantly parse xml in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have this piece of code building up sentences from XML looking like follows. I wonder what might be an alternative code, that would be more readable after being hacked to work.

```
     (mapcat
        (fn [el]
           (map special-join
              (map
                  (fn [el] (map zip-xml/text (zip-xml/xml-> el :word)))
                  (zip-xml/xml-> el :sentence))))
        (zip-xml/xml-> root :document))
```

The above code is not very readable, given the repeat inline function definitions combined with the nested probing, but tearing them apart into standalone functions as in [this official tutorial](https://github.com/clojuredocs/guides/blob/master/articles/tutorials/parsing_xml_with_zippers.md) really doesn't make sense to me for such simple cases.

For completeness, here's the repeat XML structure that this is parsing

```
<document>
  <sentence id="1">
    <word id="1.1">Foo</w>
    <word id="1.2">bar</w>
  </sentence>
</document>
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: A list of strings, each string being a sentence

Answer (score 5):

Zippers may be overkill in this situation. `clojure.xml/parse` will give you a simple data structure representing the HTML.

```
(require '[clojure.xml :as xml] '[clojure.string :as string])

(def doc
  (->
"<document>
  <sentence id=\"1\">
    <word id=\"1.1\">
      Foo
    </word>
    <word id=\"1.2\">
      bar
    </word>
  </sentence>
</document>
" .getBytes java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. xml/parse))
```

Then you can use `xml-seq` to get all the `<sentence>` tags and their children, gathering the children's text content, trimming whitespace, and joining with spaces.

```
(->> doc
  xml-seq
  (filter (comp #{:sentence} :tag))
  (map :content)
  (map #(transduce
          (comp
            (mapcat :content)
            (map string/trim)
            (interpose " "))
          str %)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the way zippers work in Clojure, and I've not looked at `clojure.zip/xml-zip` or `clojure.data.zip/xml->` (confusing that they are two separate libs!).

Instead, may I suggest you try out the `tupelo.forest` library?  Here is [an overview from the 2017 Clojure/Conj](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM).

Below is a live solution using `tupelo.forest`. I added a second sentence to make it more interesting:

```
(dotest
  (with-forest (new-forest)
    (let [xml-str        (ts/quotes->double
                           "<document>
                              <sentence id='1'>
                                <word id='1.1'>foo</word>
                                <word id='1.2'>bar</word>
                              </sentence>
                              <sentence id='2'>
                                <word id='2.1'>beyond</word>
                                <word id='2.2'>all</word>
                                <word id='2.3'>recognition</word>
                              </sentence>
                            </document>")

          root-hid       (add-tree-xml xml-str)
          >>             (remove-whitespace-leaves)
          bush-no-blanks (hid->bush root-hid)
          sentence-hids  (find-hids root-hid [:document :sentence])
          sentences      (forv [sentence-hid sentence-hids]
                           (let [word-hids     (hid->kids sentence-hid)
                                 words         (mapv #(grab :value (hid->leaf %)) word-hids)
                                 sentence-text (str/join \space words)]
                             sentence-text))
          ]
      (is= bush-no-blanks
        [{:tag :document}
         [{:id "1", :tag :sentence}
          [{:id "1.1", :tag :word, :value "foo"}]
          [{:id "1.2", :tag :word, :value "bar"}]]
         [{:id "2", :tag :sentence}
          [{:id "2.1", :tag :word, :value "beyond"}]
          [{:id "2.2", :tag :word, :value "all"}]
          [{:id "2.3", :tag :word, :value "recognition"}]]])
      (is= sentences
        ["foo bar"
         "beyond all recognition"]))))
```

The idea is to find the `hid` (Hex ID, like a pointer) for each sentence. In the `forv` loop, we find the child nodes for each sentence, extract the `:value`, and joint into a string. The unit tests show the tree structure as parsed from XML (after deleting blank nodes) and the final result. Note that we ignore the `id` fields and use only the tree structure to understand the sentences.

Documentation for `tupelo.forest` is still a work in progress, but you can [see many live examples here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.cljc).

The Tupelo project [lives on GitHub](http://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/).\

---

## Update

I have been thinking about the streaming data problem, and have added a new function `proc-tree-enlive-lazy` to enable lazy processing of large data sets.  Here is an example:

```
  (let [xml-str (ts/quotes->double
                  "<document>
                     <sentence id='1'>
                       <word id='1.1'>foo</word>
                       <word id='1.2'>bar</word>
                     </sentence>
                     <sentence id='2'>
                       <word id='2.1'>beyond</word>
                       <word id='2.2'>all</word>
                       <word id='2.3'>recognition</word>
                     </sentence>
                   </document>")
    (let [enlive-tree-lazy     (clojure.data.xml/parse (StringReader. xml-str))
          doc-sentence-handler (fn [root-hid]
                                 (remove-whitespace-leaves)
                                 (let [sentence-hid  (only (find-hids root-hid [:document :sentence]))
                                       word-hids     (hid->kids sentence-hid)
                                       words         (mapv #(grab :value (hid->leaf %)) word-hids)
                                       sentence-text (str/join \space words)]
                                   sentence-text))
          result-sentences     (proc-tree-enlive-lazy enlive-tree-lazy
                                 [:document :sentence] doc-sentence-handler)]
      (is= result-sentences ["foo bar" "beyond all recognition"])) ))
```

The idea is that you process successive subtrees, in this case whenever you get a subtree path of `[:document :sentence]`.  You pass in a *handler* function, which will receive the `root-hid` of a `tupelo.forest tree`. The return value of the handler is then placed onto an output lazy sequence returned to the caller.

Comment: I may try this library on my next time around with XML and clojure. I concur that the xml zipping namespacing is confusing. I guess tupelo forests have similar [memory implications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16303011/1509695) as the xml zippers, when it comes to processing huge forests though.

Comment: Maybe using [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive) would be another solution in some simple cases.